# Is PHP Compliable with CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

i was wondering if i could use this command:

```
<?php
         include_once "example.css"
 ?>
```

inside a PHP file so for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE CSS>
     <?php
         include_once "example1.css"
     ?>

     <?php
         include_once "example2.css"
     ?>

     <?php
         include_once "example3.css"
     ?>
```

I want to use this because the website I am trying to make is about 8000 lines of CSS long and I want to break it up into multiple CSS files for example about.css, footer.css etc. but the problem is when I try to link 10 different CSS files to one of my pages it glitches out because I have to many linked so can I do the above example with CSS and PHP?

Answer (score 2):

One way to include a bunch of css files would be like so:

```
<?php
$css = [

    'example1.css',
    'example2.css',
    'example3.css'
]

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php foreach($css as $file): ?>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo($file) ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your content -->
</body>
</html>
```

BTW, there is no "CSS" doctype - a doctype always denotes some kind of HTML/XML document:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype

Also, you might want to read about the basic structure of an HTML document:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure

Regarding the `foreach` syntax used above, see:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: You're very welcome. If the answer was helpful - maybe you'd consider accepting it?

Comment: i would if i knew how haha

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.

You can include any type of file, and it will be treated as if it were in inserted into the PHP script outside a `<?php ?>` section. So if the file doesn't contain any `<?php`, it will just be output literally.

Comment: How do you set up the file?

Comment: You do it exactly as you wrote in the question.

Comment: when I did it like I did my example above it came up with multiple errors

Comment: ok so I did it exactly, as shown above, I named the file "main.php" and copied exactly as shown above yet I just changed around the file names so they were correct but when I view my site in chrome nothing gets applied.

Comment: Use `View Source` to see if the CSS is being sent.

Comment: Why are you doing it by including CSS into the PHP? Why not use `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="example1.css">`?

Comment: im not sure how to use view source and Im not using <link> because when i had 10 style sheets all linked at once none of them worked

Comment: There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to use 10 style sheets. If it's not working, it's a bug in your code, not because you're trying to link too many.

Comment: In Chrome, `View Source` is in the View->Developer menu.

Comment: @GeorgeAdamson the number of stylesheets would not be the problem. Something else was probably the issue. Learn how to use your browser's Developer Tools to debug such issues. P.s. View Source is usually available in your browser's menu or via a keyboard shortcut - e.g. Ctrl+U in Chrome

Comment: do you know a site online that have people who will look for errors in your code?

Comment: No, I doubt you'll find a free service like that. If you have any hope of being a web developer, you need to learn to do it yourself.